# Azure Cosmosdb query runs fine in portal but not in text string

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

My query string is propperly escaped:

```
"g.addV('planet').property('name','D\\PA')
  .property('class','terrestrial')
  .property('objid','2875301669077')
  .property('label','planet')
  .property('radius',0.0814)
  .property('mass',0.9808)
  .property('isSupportsLife','True')
  .property('isPopulated','True')
  .property('isHomeworld','True')
  .property('username','BillmanLocal2')
  .property('objtype','planet')"
```

Running the same query in the portal seems fine:
[image]

But running it as a string in `callback = self.c.submitAsync(query)` fashion causes the exception:

```
GraphSyntaxException
Gremlin query syntax error: Unexpected token: ; in input: 'g.addV('planet').property('name',''. @ line 1, column 34.
```

Is it possible that Azure's Cosmos is doing some cleaning in the process?

Comment: Just to relate to context, the GH issue is here: https://github.com/BillmanH/exoplanets/issues/72